# How do I load data from azure databricks to an premise SQL Database tables?

Tags: sql-server, azure-databricks

First of all I have created an azure databricks notebook and cluster and able to access the data from the datalake.

Now I have to load this data into on premise SQL database tables.how can I load the data from azure databricks to one premise SQL.

I have seen there are spark connectors but not able to load it.

P.S. My destination is not Azure SQL database,it is on premise SQL database

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SQL Databases using JDBC.

> Databricks Runtime contains JDBC drivers for **Microsoft SQL Server** and **Azure SQL Database**.

**Steps to Connect your Azure Databricks Workspace to your on-premises network:**

This is a high-level guide on how to establish connectivity from your Azure Databricks workspace to your on-premises network. It is based on the hub-and-spoke topology shown in the following diagram, where traffic is routed via a transit virtual network (VNet) to the on-premises network.

> This process requires your **Azure Databricks workspace to be deployed in your own virtual network** (also known as VNet injection).

[image]

**Step 1:** Set up a transit virtual network with Azure Virtual Network Gateway

**Step 2:** Peer the Azure Databricks virtual network with the transit virtual network

**Step 3:** Create user-defined routes and associate them with your Azure Databricks virtual network subnets

**Step 4:** Validate the setup

**Reference:** [Connect your Azure Databricks Workspace to your on-premises network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network)

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.